# Plotting a vector change over time (steps)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, multidimensional-array

I have a 100-dimensional vector (array) as a result from a function, and I would like to see its change during "time", that is at every step, the elements in my vector assume different values, in a single plot, for every value of the 100 in the vector. What I should get is something like this:[image: Whatt I would like to get]

In my context, I have:

```
def consensus_dynamic(x_0,t):
    L=csgraph.laplacian(Last_adj)
    x_t=np.dot(linalg.expm(-t*L),x_0)
    return x_t
```

x_t is the 100-dim vector I want to use in the plot, and t the "time".
For arbitrary x_0 and t I should obtain that type of graph.
I used:

```
x_0=np.arange(100)
t = np.logspace(-2.5,1.5,100)
```

Then
`x_t=consensus_dynamic(x_0,t)`
and with

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xscale('log')
plt.plot(t,x_t)
plt.show()
```

I get this [image: What I get]

Can someone help me please?

EDIT: after some tries, I used this code, which computes my vector at every step of t:

```
steps=[]
for i in t:
    x_i=consensus_dynamic(x_0,i)
    steps.append(x_i)
plt.plot(t,steps)
plt.show()
```

And I get this:[image: New trial]

I don't know if this is right, but seems closer to the solution than before.

Comment: Your `Last_adj` variable is undeclared. Could you add a declaration to your code?

Comment: @jylls it is an adjacency matrix of a connected graph with 100 nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I accomplished it:

```
t = np.logspace(-2.5,1.5,100)
x_0=np.arange(100)
steps=[]
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('time')
ax.set_ylabel('x(t)')
for i in t:
    x_i=consensus_dynamic(x_0,i)
    steps.append(x_i)
plt.plot(t,steps)
plt.show()
```

[image: Got it]